# TypeError: success is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can somebody help me to get this fixed.
In fact I'm trying to register a new user and before creating a new one I have to check if the username exists or not. below is the factory used for that.

```
.factory('accountService', function($resource, sessionService) {
    var service = {};
    service.register = function(account, success, failure) {
        if (success (service.userExists(account))){
            failure();
        } else {
            var Account = $resource("/Test/rest/account/student");
            Account.save({}, account, success, failure);
        }            
    };

    service.userExists = function(account, success, failure) {
        var Account = $resource("/Test/rest/account");
        var data = Account.get({
                username : account.username,
                password : account.password
            }, function() {
                var accounts = data.username;
                if (accounts && accounts.length !== 0) {
                    service.data = data;
                    success(account);
                } else {
                    failure();
                }
            }, failure);
    };

    service.getuser = function() {
        return service.data;
    };

    return service;
})
```

but when I run it, i get this error message:

> TypeError: success is not a function

below is the controller that uses this factory

```
.controller(
            "RegisterController",
            function($scope, sessionService, $state, accountService) {
                $scope.register = function() {
                    accountService.register($scope.account, function(
                            returnedata) {
                        sessionService.login($scope.account).then(
                                function() {
                                    $state.go("home");
                                });
                    }, function() {
                        $scope.registererror = function() {
                        }
                    });
                };
            })
```

Comment: You need to provide some more information so we can help you. Best way is to create some Fiddle or Plunker to isolate the problem.

Comment: How are you running your code? we see the factory and would like to know what is producing the error

Comment: when you are calling service.userExists(account), you are not passing your success and failure callback, which is expected in the userExists function's definition. That is why you are getting error "success" undefined. Have you defined these in some other code, which you have not mentioned here?

Comment: @Sze-HungDanielTsui the problem is on the if condition which is generating an error as success() is not a function.

Comment: @YashikaGarg no, that's my problem; Should I define it in the userExists function or in another place? can you help me to set that. thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears to be from this line: `success (service.userExists(account))`, but it shouldn't throw until you try to invoke `register()`, which you don't seem to have, yet. That's why we think were is more code being run that is throwing the error, not just the factory breaking on you. I agree with Sargo, we need more information to help you...

Comment: @Sze-HungDanielTsui I added the controller that uses the factory, I hope that helps.

Comment: @SargoDarya I added the Controller that uses this factory, is that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.factory(
            'accountService',
            function($resource, sessionService) {
                var service = {};
                service.register = function(account, success, failure) {
                    service
                            .validUserName(
                                    account,
                                    function(answer) {
                                        if (answer) {
                                            console.log(answer);
                                            failure();
                                        } else {
                                            var Account = $resource("/Test/rest/account/student");
                                            Account.save({}, account,
                                                    success, failure);
                                        }
                                    }, failure);
                };
                service.userExists = function(account, success, failure) {
                    var Account = $resource("/Test/rest/account");
                    var data = Account.get({
                        username : account.username,
                        password : account.password
                    }, function() {
                        console.log("user details : ", data);
                        var accounts = data.username;
                        if (accounts && accounts.length !== 0) {
                            service.data = data;
                            success(account);
                        } else {
                            failure();
                        }
                    }, failure);
                };
                service.validUserName = function(account, success, failure) {
                    var Account = $resource("/Test/rest/account/user");
                    var data = Account.get({
                        username : account.username
                    }, function() {
                        var accounts = data.username;
                        if (accounts && accounts.length !== 0) {
                            service.data = data;
                            success(true);
                        } else {
                            success(false);
                        }
                    }, failure);
                };
                service.getuser = function() {
                    return service.data;
                };
                return service;
            })
```

and for the controller:

```
.controller(
            "RegisterController",
            function($scope, sessionService, $state, accountService) {
                $scope.register = function() {
                    accountService.register($scope.account, function(
                            returnedata) {
                        accountService.userExists($scope.account, function(
                                account) {
                            sessionService.login($scope.account).then(
                                    function() {
                                        $state.go("get_started");
                                    });
                        });

                    }, function() {
                        $scope.registererror = function() {
                        }
                    });
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that error is in this line

> service.userExists(account)

Your method signature is

> service.userExists = function(account, success, failure)

so then you call it "success" will be undefined in this case and
this line inside "service.userExists"

> success(account)

throws a error

Here is rewritten approximately example of how to avoid this error, notes about changes. We need to distinguish between failure and user existence, I've just changed returnData in "success" to true/false for the sake of an example.

```
.factory('accountService', function($resource, sessionService) {
var service = {};
service.register = function(account, success, failure) {
  service.userExists(account), function(answer){
       if (answer){
           success();
       } else {
           var Account = $resource("/Test/rest/account/student");
           Account.save({}, account, success, failure);
       }
  }, failure);        
};

service.userExists = function(account, success, failure) {
    var Account = $resource("/Test/rest/account");
    var data = Account.get({
            username : account.username,
            password : account.password
        }, function() {
            var accounts = data.username;
            if (accounts && accounts.length !== 0) {
                service.data = data;
                success(true);
            } else {
                success(false);
            }
        }, failure);
};

service.getuser = function() {
    return service.data;
};

return service;
```

})

Comment: yep that's the problem, but how can I get it fixed

Comment: @MohamedNAOUALI, I added changes to 'accountService' to my response. Edited both register and userExists methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
service.userExists = function(account, success, failure)
```

...

```
if (success (service.userExists(account)))
```

Calling a 3 method param with only one param.

Comment: the problem is not in the param passed to the method but how to set up the success and failure callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (success (service.userExists(account)))
```

here the script wants to call the function success(param). So you have to define the success() method or you need to check it by another way. it should look like

```
if(service.userExists(account)){ 
  failure(); //also needs to be defined!
} else{
  var Account = $resource("/Test/rest/account/student");
  Account.save({}, account, success, failure);
}
```

you really need to take care of what you are calling ->

```
var test = "hello";
console.log(test); //-> prints "hello"

var test = function(){
  console.log("hello")
}
console.log(test); //-> prints sth. like "function()....."
console.log(test()); //-> prints "hello"
```